# Is it Possible to load both source and target values from Property File while mapping in mapstruct?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I want to create Object to Object Binding, So I Choose Map struct API. My Requirement is that instead of keeping both source and target string in Java Class,  I want to load both source and target from Different File and inject into the Mapper Class, while building the application.

```
@Mapper
public interface SimpleSourceDestinationMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source ="name", target="tgName")

    })
    SimpleDestination sourceToDestination(SimpleSource source);
}
```

I want to load source's name and target's tgName from Properties file.

something like this

```
@Mapping(source ="${mapstruct.source.name}", target="${mapstruct.destination.name}")

application.properties
mapstruct.source.name=name
mapstruct.destination.name=tgName
```

Comment: Please add some (psuedo) code to help clarify and explain the issue.

Comment: Hi @AndrewS I have added Psuedo code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know. MapStruct is an annotation processor which analyses the `@Mapping` annotation compile time.

Besides, annotation parameters require true constants. You cannot resolve them from a resource bundle or property file.

Not sure whether this is going to work, but you could consider writing your own extension (processor). MapStruct concatenates processors. The first kicks off and determines which ones should be run. Default, there's a processor that analyses the source code and builds up the source model, the `MethodRetrievalProcessor` followed by a processor that builds the internal model the `MapperCreationProcessor`, etc.

MapStruct allows for addition of custom processors in this chain. But it requires knowledge of the MapStruct internal workings.